# How to change default registration form?

Tags: 7

By default, user registration form in Drupal 7 takes 2 fields: "Username" and "Email."

I want users to set their password directly upon Registration.

Take 4 fields:
- Username
- Password
- Confirm Password
- Email

How can I do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In  *Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings*, uncheck the *Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account.* option. This will allow user to directly enter their password on the registration form.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a module called [logintoboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) that can really save you tons of time.